# datetime.date.fromtimestamp: ignores hour and minute

Tags: python, datetime

The following code returns `'2012-06-07 00:00'` for both the timestamp `1339119900000` and `1339120800000`:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.fromtimestamp(1339119900000/1e3).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
'2012-06-07 00:00'
>>> date.fromtimestamp(1339120800000/1e3).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
'2012-06-07 00:00'
```

However, these timestamps are 15 minutes apart, and neither of them are exactly midnight.

I'm running 32bit Python 2.7.3 on a Windows 7 machine, but noticed the same on a Red Hat machine. Why is this and how can I get hour and minute resolution from a timestamp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating *`date`* objects, not `datetime`. Dates ignore all time information.

Use `datetime` objects instead if you want to preserve the time component:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1339119900000/1e3).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
'2012-06-08 02:45'
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1339120800000/1e3).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
'2012-06-08 03:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

`date` does not have hours or minutes use `datetime.datetime`

```
>>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1339119900000/1e3).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
'2012-06-08 03:45'
```